# Is there a solution to generalize this method?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I need a method in my base data access class like this:

```
    public virtual void InitializaEntity(T entity, object relatedEntity)
    {
        using (session)
        {
            T mergedEntity = (T)session.Merge(entity);
            NHibernateUtil.Initialize(relatedEntity);
        }
    }
```

I want to initialize a related object to a main object lazily. I can use a method like below for every relation but i like to generalize that method.

```
    public Keyword GetKeywordCategoryByKewordId(long id)
    {
        Keyword k = session.Get<Keyword>(id);
        NHibernateUtil.Initialize(k.Categories);

        session.Close();

        return k;
    }
```

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear what it is you want generalising, but:

You say you want to load them lazily, but if you're *always* immediately calling `Initialize` then you might as well turn lazy loading off. Alternatively, if you're in a web app, you can use a session per request, forget about having to close the session yourself and lazy load to your heart's content.

Comment: I have a windows application. I load my entities lazily but in some cases I want load these entities eagerly. Now I want to add a general method in my base dao class to load a entity with its dependent entity eagerly. I don't want to write a method in every dao classes.